# Chrome 5 : Login failure

Tags: bug, status-declined, login

With Chrome 5 browser I am not able to login. (*Using wordpress login.) Could it be a browser specific issue / or something related to implementation at the your end?.

Update: I am also seeing some alignment issues (Specifically comment answering button alignment) on Chrome 5.

Comment: with which openid? yahoo?

Comment: are you on a mac? Chrome 5 is currently broken due to bugs from what we're seeing.

Comment: Re-opened, because the browser rtm'd and the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't support beta browsers. Can you try with a released browser?

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm the login issue using Chrome 5 on OS X, and add some additional clarification.

Typically when I login to and SO sites I don't bother clicking any OpenID buttons. Instead I simply type in my OpenID and hit enter. Where Chrome 5 seems to be having issues is if I don't enter the preceding http://. If I enter the full OpenID URL it works as expected. If I leave off http:// nothing happens.

Comment: I can confirm this

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is an issue with the RTM, released on 05.25.2010.  The "http://" workaround mentioned by John Clayton does work, however.

Comment: Just a bit more information - Google Chrome 5.0.375.55, Windows 7 Enterprise x64.